# Verificação em formulário de login

Tags: c#, mysql

Não estou conseguindo fazer uma verificação no banco de dados, para certificar que o usuário existe. Segue o código:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conexao = "SERVER = localhost; DATABASE = dizimistas; UID = root; PASSWORD = senha00789;";
    string query = "SELECT idusuario FROM USUARIOS WHERE nomeusuario = @usuario and senhausuario = @senha;";

    using (MySqlConnection objConexao = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
    {
        objConexao.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, objConexao);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", txtUsuario);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", txtSenha);

            int? id = (int?)command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                FormPrincipal form = new FormPrincipal();
                form.Show();
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou senha inválidos!");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            objConexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Se a query retornar verdadeiro (Usuário existe), ai ele vai ser levado a outro formulário. Porém tudo que coloco nesse IF, o visual studio não aceita.

Comment: Fora a comparação que não faz sentido, falta executar a _query_, né?

Comment: Sou novo no C#. Desculpa ser leigo! Pra mim o objData.SelectCommand tava executando a query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caro Pedro, em primeiro lugar, nunca use concatenação de strings para montar suas clausulas SQL. Assim você evita o [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Montei um exemplo de como ficaria utilizando parâmetros.

```
string conexao = "SERVER = localhost; DATABASE = dizimistas; UID = root; PASSWORD = senha00789;";
string query = "SELECT idusuario FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario = @usuario and senha = @senha;";

using (MySqlConnection objConexao = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
{
    objConexao.Open();
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, objConexao);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", txtUsuario);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", txtSenha);

        var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {

        }
    }
    finally
    {
        objConexao.Close();
    }                
}
```

A clausula [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) fornece uma sintaxe conveniente que garante o uso correto de objetos [IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.idisposable).
Uso o `try finally` após abrir a conexão, para garantir que ao concluir toda a operação dentro do `try` a conexão seja sempre fechada.

Comment: Pablo, tem dois "@usuario", quando compilo o programa e clico em login, não acontece nada. Olha se fiz certo a chamada para o novo formulário:                     if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        FormPrincipal form = new FormPrincipal();
                        form.Show();
                    }

Comment: corregi a questão de ter dois @usuario, no copiar e colar não editei. Fiz uma alteração na execução do comando também, troquei para o ExecuteScalar. E a execução do Form seria basicamente isso ai mesmo.

Comment: Adaptei um else,                     var usuario = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (usuario != null)
                    {
                        FormPrincipal form = new FormPrincipal();
                        form.Show();
                    } else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Usúario ou senha inválidos!");
                    }

Tá sempre caindo no else, a senha e o usuário estão certinhos.

Comment: Vale lembrar que para funções de banco de dados seria melhor utilizar uma outra camada, e não diretamente no clique do botão!

Comment: Faltava um pouco de conhecimento meu sobre o ExecuteScalar, mas já corrigi a resposta e adicionei alguns detalhes a mais.

Comment: Ainda continua caindo no else de senha ou usuario invalido :(

Comment: Pedro, coloque um breackpoint e verifique as variáveis txtUsuario e txtSenha, acredito que esses dois sejam componentes visuais, sendo eles componentes visuais, coloque um .Text no final para pegar o valor digitado pelo usuário.

Comment: Agora foi! Porém ta dando esse erro no IF(id.HasValue): System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversão especificada não é válida.'

Comment: na sua tabela `USUARIOS`, qual o nome e tipo da chave primária?

Comment: int(11) unsigned zerofill, auto_increment. Nome: idusuario

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69433/discussion-between-pablo-tondolo-de-vargas-and-pedro-ribeiro).

Comment: Fiz uma edição na resposta, olha os comentários no chat.